# Merging as of a date

Tags: sas

I am trying to merge two tables. table A has an id column, a date column, and an amount value for every date in a period

Table B has both id and date, but also other columns with details. However, there is only one entry any time there is a change in the details, so I do not know how to merge with normal joins. I want that for every entry in A, the details are populated as of the latest day available in B for that ID before the date in A.

```
Table A
| ID | date | amount |
| 1  | 01JAN| 56     |
| 1  | 02JAN| 54     |
| 1  | 03JAN| 23     |
| 1  | 04JAN| 43     |

Table B
| ID | date | details|
| 1  | 01JAN|    x   |
| 1  | 03JAN|    y   |
```

Wanted Output

```
Table A
| ID | date | amount | details |
| 1  | 01JAN| 56     |   x     |
| 1  | 02JAN| 54     |   x     |
| 1  | 03JAN| 23     |   y     |
| 1  | 04JAN| 43     |   y     |
```

for the jan2 entry, the latest available details as of that date is 'x', for jan3 it is y

Thank you in advance for any guidance you could provide

Comment: can you add some data examples

Comment: @SanekZhitnik just did

Comment: you can use retain statement to prepare table B. then use merge statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the question you have asked literally:

```
data want;
  retain details_last;
  merge table1 table2;
  by ID date;
  if not missing(details) then details_last = details;
  else details = details_last;
  drop details_last;
run;
```

But this will only work if your data meets the conditions that you have presented like the date ranges in table B should always fall within the date ranges in table A and not outside (i.e. only interpolation, no extrapolation).

Comment: Thank you! It is only interpolation (For any ID , the latest date in table A is always going to be later than the latest date in table B). There are more than 1 detail column (detail1, detail2, etc), but I will try to adapt it.